# isLockerServiceEnabled cannot be changed to false until isRelaxedCSPLevel is set to true

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, experience-bundle

I am trying to deploy experiences folder using sfdx to a sandbox/production and getting following error. It was working fine until API version 54.0 but we had to switch to 55.0 when we started to use flows. Currently using API version 56.0 but still facing same issue in deployment of experienceBundle.

> The value for isLockerServiceEnabled in
> customer/config/loginAppPage.json cannot be changed to false until
> isRelaxedCSPLevel is set to true

```
{
  "cmsSettings" : { },
  "id" : "a_random_id",
  "label" : "login",
  "templateName" : "Login Template",
  "type" : "appPage"
}
```

I have gone through the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) and have tried all combination of "isLockerServiceEnabled" and "isRelaxedCSPLevel" property in loginAppPage.json but nothing worked. I even tried to convert the code to metadata api format and used ANT Migration tool's sf:deploy approach but that also gave same error message.

Any help/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the org id in which this is happening so I can check further? Thanks

Comment: Following up to see if the issue is already fixed or if you looking for assistance

Comment: Hello Sweta, I am still facing the issue but I have apprehensions in sharing the Org Id at a public forum. Is there any other way I can share this with you where it does not go in public domain.

Comment: Are you able to log a case with salesforce support and share the case number here so I can take it forward? Thanks

Comment: Case #43836024 created on 28 Dec 2022.

Comment: Thank you. I will coordinate with you via the support case.

Comment: Can you run a test in your sandbox org that has 242 release rolled out? Thanks

Comment: Performed the test on a sandbox which has Spring 23 release preview using same steps reported in Case #43836024 and I am still facing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @Amit. From the investigation, I see that the fix would be live in the 242.8 patch (Week of 2/6/2023)(Safe Harbour). I'd suggest testing after the patch release next week. I will again check in with you. Thanks

Comment: Could you test and let me know if you are all set?

Comment: Swetha, we have verified and found that issue is fixed with 242.8 patch.

Comment: Thank you for confirming @Amit Jain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As communicated on the support case, the issue you are facing has been identified as a bug by the salesforce product team. While there is no workaround at the moment, the ETA for the fix is Spring'23(Safe Harbour). Please take bug reference `#W-12297203` tagged to this investigation.

---

Update(15/02/2023)

The issue has been fixed in 242.8 patch release